# The event horizon of a black hole is a spacetime codimension 1 null surface

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, event-horizon

The event horizon of a black hole is a spacetime codimension 1 null surface.

Why must the event horizon be a codimension 1 surface?

Why must it be a null surface?

**Edit:**

For reference, see the footnote on page 4 of the [article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1501.00007) on The AdS/CFT correspondence by Veronika Hubeny.

Comment: Please see the edit to my post.

Comment: I made a mistake, I'll rewrite. Actually, surface with 2 spatial dimensions is 3D in spacetime (since we add time). So the codimension is $4-3=1$. Other part stays the same:
"Null surface has null (i.e. ds2=0ds2=0) normal vectors. Everything travels at the speed of light along that surface."

Comment: Codimension 2 objects in GR are cosmic strings, and they have interesting property of angular deficiency.

Comment: It is null because it is a causal boundary. It is codimension 1 because it is a boundary.